# How to get root access for Android Emulator running Android 7.0?

Tags: root-access

I am trying to get root access to the Android Emulator running Android 7.0. I found a nice description at the end of this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095234/how-to-get-root-access-on-android-emulator
However it doesn't work.

`adb root` does not give me root access.

The following  `adb remount` returns:
`Not running as root. Try "adb root" first.`

Help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you are using an `adb server version` not matching​ the emulator version (client). In other words the adb version on your system is different from the adb version on the android sdk platform-tools.

So try this:

- Navigate to the platform tools folder (`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Android\Android-sdk\Platform tools\`)
- Open command-prompt (or teminal) by right click + shift
- Disconnect any USB cables and close other instances of emulator devices.
- Now try `adb devices` and make sure it lists the emulator device and is not blank.

*Note: If this fails first run `adb kill-server`*

- Now run `adb root` command
- Root your virtual device [as per instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44473415/7551330)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Genymotion emulator and install Marshmallow or N, then you can have root access in default.

Comment: I know but Genymotion is not free.

Comment: I also tried Nox which is rooted by default. It works very well for a while on the computer on which it has to run (runs under Windows XP and that ca not be changed) but unfortunately it freezes after a while (~ 1 to 2 hrs).

Comment: Genymotion is free for personal use but I don't know about the nox.